# Consequences of downgrading from windows 8 to XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8

I want to download this old game I found, Roller Coaster Tycoon 3 Platinum. I am on windows 8 currently and it can only be run on windows "98/ME/2000/XP". I am curious what would be the best to download, and how dangerous/permanent/possible it would be.

Comment: Have you tried it on Windows 8?  What errors have you run into?   Windows 8 didn't exist when those specs were published, but it will likely work on 8 if it works on XP.

Comment: I have tried running it on windows 8, and 7. My windows 8 stopped mid download (3 times in a row with an error "Data Error (cylic redundancy check)." My brother's windows 7 stopped as well. I tried each of the OS's 2 times

Comment: The requirements were printed before Win8 was released. Any requirements (99% of the time) mean the printed version and up.

Comment: download failure? so you haven't even installed it to know if it will run on Windows 7 in compatibility mode then... Betcha it's going to have a download failure on XP as well.

Comment: Cyclic Redundancy Check? I haven't seen that since Windows XP where it was an issue with the CD/DVD drive. By download, I assume you mean install?

Comment: `Data Error (cylic redundancy check)`? Then you might also have a problem with this in Windows XP. Is this from a CD because this sounds like a disc-read error.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and ideas. But unfortunately I

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and ideas. But unfortunately I found that the disc is, in fact, unreadable. I appreciate all the effort, but the disc is scratched and cannot be played

Comment: @Kyle Unless the scratch is on the top of the disk, you can polish it out. The data is on the top and is read through the plastic.

Comment: I'd suggest that downgrading to XP to run a specific game would be something like performing an amputation because you have a papercut. *Especially* taking into account the circumstances.

Comment: Note that windows XP is no longer fully supported since 2009 (over 4 years ago) and that [extended support will end the 8th of april](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/lifecycle). If you have a box which needs to run XP after this date you will no longer get any updates at all for it. So Unplug it from the network and glue shut all the USB ports and CDROMs to keep it secure.

Answer (score 5):

Virtual Machines are the best option you have! [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) are the two popular options.

To clarify what virtual machine is, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine):

> A virtual machine (VM) is a software based, fictive computer. Virtual
>   machines may be based on specifications of a hypothetical computer or
>   emulate the computer architecture and functions of a real world
>   computer.

You can simply download one of the virtual machine software, install your XP in one of them and play the game there instead of downgrading from 8 to XP! You have to refer to their website for installation instructions. VirtualBox is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

XP is on the end of its suprisingly long shuffle towards obsolesce. The world has moved on, and we have shiny things like composited desktops, and less obvious and more awesome things like better security protocols.

Hardware has moved on - you'll have trouble finding drivers, and as time goes on, less and less software will support your system. You'll be stuck with older versions without the benefit of new features.

Your system might even be one that uses UEFI, and XP may not know what to do with it without tricking it into thinking its a classic bios (never tried it myself).

Soon it would have rode of into the sunset, or more accurately, needs to be taken out the back, shot. We need to bury XP, not praise it.

In short, its a terrible idea - especially to run a game.

On the other hand, this game exists on steam, and looking at the specs, there's no plausible reason it wouldn't run on a modern OS. For really old games, picking it off steam or GOG is a good idea if you want to play a game, but can't be bothered to keep track of the media or beating it into running.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to run the game in compatibility mode.

Downgrading to XP from 8 would be taking a huge step backwards in functionality. Not to mention, if you are using a newer PC, or a PC with 64-bit drivers, you may not be able to find equivalents for 32-bit XP.

Why not run XP in a virtual machine, then run the game on there? You can find plenty of information about that around.

Comment: I apologize for not understanding, but what is a VM? And how would I get XP on there to begin with?

Comment: Installing an operating system on a virtual machine is essentially the same as installing it on a regular computer. You'll just need to download the virtualization program and select the disc or disc image. If you have a Windows XP disc you can just put it in your drive (while your computer is already running) and you'll be able to select it during the new machine wizard (at least in VirtualBox). Then you just walk through the install as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 or 8.1 you have the Virtual Machine Hyper-V just enable it and install Windows XP in it. Or try to run the game in the compatibility mode. You can even install Windows XP to dual boot with Windows 8, but do not downgrade Windows 8 to XP just for a game.

Windows 8 is a modern OS, it is more secure, has better performance, is more reliable and in general is in every aspect better than Windows XP. A downgrade would be a huge step backwards.

Answer (score -1):

just buy a used xp box for $99 or so at a discount store.  Put all the older stuff on it.
you can get them for $25 or free if you go to garage sales, etc.
forget messing with installs, and all that SW .

Comment: Pay a 100$ just for not messing with installs and all that SW. You must be rich, sir!

Comment: Well, I tend to keep our older, obsolete boxen for stuff like that. Its not a very bad idea in the wider scheme of things

Comment: Keeping thins is the way to go, not spending extra cash on old stuff. I, too, keep old stuff: got 2 very old PCs for home-servers (multimedia etc). It's good to have them.